# Android studio not publishing artifact to Artifactory

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory, android-studio-3.0

I'm facing an odd problem with Android Studio and Artifactory. I want to publish a module from Android Studio. The problem being, the build info is published just fine but the artifacts are not published.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.5.4"
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release'
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
}
```

module/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

def packageName = 'x.x'
def libraryVersion = 'v1.0.0'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 10000
        versionName libraryVersion

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId packageName
            version = libraryVersion
            artifactId "y"

            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/$archivesBaseName-release.aar")
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    publish {
        defaults {
            publications('aar')

            publishArtifacts = true
            publishBuildInfo = false
            publishPom = true
            publishIvy = false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

When I run `./gradlew assembleRelease artifactoryPublish` from the terminal, I always get the following output:

```
> Task :minecommon:artifactoryPublish
Deploying build descriptor to: https://artifactory-domain/artifactory/api/build
Build successfully deployed. Browse it in Artifactory under https://artifactory-domain/artifactory/webapp/builds/project-name/1509633107114


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
26 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 25 up-to-date
```

I can find the build in the "Build Browser" of my Artifactory.

Is there something wrong with my configuration? How can I make gradle publish my artifacts?

I've tries every article I could find on this issue to no resolve.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having same issue

Comment: At the time, I was using Artifactory OSS edition and it did not support AAR files. Now I use nexus OSS but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working finally

Comment: @GokhanArik How did you finally got this working?

Comment: @laborg I can't remember now, it's been a while, sorry. It might be related to running it from module vs project, or having credentials in wrong place.